# Minimum swaps from matrix A to matrix B

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, matrix, path-finding

I have a base matrix of 2x3

```
A = 
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

Now I need to find the least possible steps to get into given matrix for example:

```
B =
1 2 5
3 4 0
```

And I can only swap digits that are adjacent with `0`.

So to actually get into the example matrix I would need to
Swap 0 with 1, then 0 with 2 and then 0 with 5 = 3 steps.

I think that I should use DFS but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 0):

To *point* you in the right direction about recursion:

In each example matrix, you have a certain (small) amount of swaps you *could* do.

So what you can do, from a given matrix, is try out each of the allowed swaps, which gives a new matrix. Then you ask, "how many swaps from THIS matrix to reach the targe matrix?". That's where the recursion comes in. You might have to keep track so you avoid visiting the same matrix twice, else you run in an endless loop.

Comment: I'm really unsure how to count the steps so I do not have the sum of all the allowed steps